# OpenGL v2.0 Shaders with Dev-C++ and SDL?

Tags: opengl, sdl, shader, dev-c++

I was about to rebuild my library in Dev-C++, under Windows; however, the shader functionality I've added in the meantime is not supported, the compiler could not find the related functions (::glCreateShader(), ::glCreateProgram(), etc.)

Digging around the internet and the Dev-C++ folder, I've found that the OpenGL implementation (gl.h) is only v1.1. I've found [recommendations](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=358499) to download the latest headers from [SGI](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/). I have found gl3.h, however, after closer scrutiny I have realized that gl.h is not included in my project anyway, and I should be looking at SDL/SDL_opengl.h.

**EDIT:** SDL_opengl.h *does* include gl.h *and* declares prototypes of the functions in question. So the question is, why ame I given compile-time errors rather than linker errors?

(My library only links against mingw32, libOpenGL32, libSDL, libSDL_Image and libSDL_Mixer, much like under OSX (except for mingw32, of course) where I didn't have any problem.)

How can I use OpenGL v2.0 shaders with Dev-C++ and SDL?

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to use Dev-C++? Do yourself a favor and use an IDE that has been updated in the last 4 years. (and which wasn't buggy and lacking in features even when it *was* supported)

Comment: Why have you chosen Dev-C++ instead of VC++2008 Express?

Comment: It's a fair point and I can't say I didn't see it coming. Windows wasn't going to be my primary platform and I loathed the juggling of manifests and the 6 flavors of MSVC runtimes. Additionally I was going to develop for GP2X, and its official devkit is a whacked-out Dev-C++, so I thought it was handy... Yeah, it's not.

Comment: Well IDE choice is a matter of taste, but DevC++ isn't updated anymore. His designated successor is Code::Blocks ( http://www.codeblocks.org/ ). So pick this one, or try others (Eclipse, VC Express) and find the one you like best, but you shouldn't be using Dev C++ anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I used to use VS, maybe I'll just go back to that. I haven't heard about Eclipse, I'll definitely check that one out and still have Code::Blocks to fall back on if it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gl.h is only for OpenGL 1.1 (and in some cases up to 1.3 depending on which version of the file you are using and which operating system). For everything else you additionally need [glext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h) and probably [glxext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glxext.h) (Linux/Unix) or [wglext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/wglext.h) (Windows).

All functions from newer versions of OpenGL must be linked at runtime. So in order to use them you must get the right function address and assign it to a function pointer. The easiest way to do this is by using something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

The manual way would be something like this:

```
PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader = NULL;
glCreateShader = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
```

or for Linux:

```
PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader = NULL;
glCreateShader = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC) glXGetProcAddress((GLubyte*) "glCreateShader");
```

If you define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES before including glext.h you can omit the first line.

**EDIT:** SDL_opengl.h looks like it contains a copy of glext.h (not up to date though). So if you use that the above should still be valid. If you want to use a seperate glext.h you must define NO_SDL_GLEXT before including SDL_opengl.h. Also, the function prototypes aren't available as long as GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES isn't defined or you write them yourself.

**EDIT2:** Apparently SDL has its own GetProcAddress function called [SDL_GL_GetProcAddress](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GL_GetProcAddress).

Comment: "Also, the function prototypes aren't available as long as GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES isn't defined or you write them yourself."
<- THAT. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the addresses of the functions at runtime?

```
typedef GLhandle (APIENTRYP PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC) (GLenum shaderType);
PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader = NULL;
glCreateShader = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");

typedef GLhandle (APIENTRYP PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC) ();
PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC glCreateProgram = NULL;
glCreateProgram = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateProgram");
```